# How to get a list of sibling pages in Kentico

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kentico

We have a MVC application that uses Kentico CMS. How can I retrieve sibling pages and child pages from a given node in content tree? Say for instance content tree looks like

```
/
---Breads
-----Foo Bread
----------Recipe X
----------Nutrition A
---Cookies
-----Bar Cookie
----------Recipe Y
----------Nutrition B
-----Foo Cookie
```

- When visitor is on Nutrition A page they should see Recipe X on side bar
- When user is on Recipe Y page, they should see Nutrition B on side bar
- If they're on Cookies page, they should see Bar Cookie and Foo Cookie on the side bar and so on.

Some examples I found use macros and I don't think I can make use of that in MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say you want get children of the current document parent on the same level,
let say you have `CurrentDocument`:

```
    var docs = DocumentHelper
        .GetDocuments()
        .OnSite("CorporateSite")
        .Culture("en-US")
        .Where(d => d.NodeParentID == CurrentDocument.NodeParentID && d.NodeLevel == CurrentDocument.NodeLevel)
        .OrderBy(d => d.DocumentName);

    // Go through the documents 
    foreach (var document in docs)
    {
        Response.Write(HTMLHelper.HTMLEncode(document.DocumentName) + "<br />");
    }
```

Read more on [DocumentHelper](https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/kentico-8-technology-documentquery-api)

Comment: Why filter on node level when you are already filtering by NodeParentID?

Comment: Just to be sure, because  it might bring all children, i.e. children of the children etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `CurrentDocument.NodeAliasPath`, this will return the current document you're on and your URL would be

`/Breads/Foo-Bread/Nutrition-A`

So you can simply use:

`CurrentDocument.Parent.NodeAliasPath + "/%"`

as your path in your API call.

Comment: Parent object is returning null no matter what page I'm on.